# nextjs - use _error.js in dev mode

Tags: error-handling, next.js

So I am creating a custom error page on my nextjs application.
Following the documentation, I created a `_error.js` file with my view in it (in `React`)

My issue is when I am in dev mode, my `_error` page is completely ignored (even though it goes through its `getInitialProps`). The `render` function seems to be ignored and instead `nextjs` seems to be using its internal `error-debug` page.

If I am right, that is what this code says [from the repo](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/9ec81c00fad040154df571701b73cb6e3b1b86fa/server/render.js) (line 84 for the current version)

When I build with as a `production` env, no problem, my custom error page is picked up.

Any idea on how to render my custom error page in dev mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set your node environment to production. In the `package.json` under scripts, before your dev command add `NODE_ENV=production ...`.

Just a guess of mine.

Comment: thanks @kalm42, but my question was basically how to fix this WITHOUT setting the node env to production (as this might have other implications)

Comment: Ahh... Then I would say add an ErrorBoundary with a fallback to your custom error page UI. The _error page is meant to make sure that your end user's don't see a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

For even easier debugging you can create new script in `package.json`:

```
...

  "scripts": {
     "dev": "next",
     "build": "next build",
     "start": "NODE_ENV=production next start",
     "prod": "npm run build; npm run start", // combine build and start in order to have easier debugging
  }

...
```

Comment: sorry cJayy, but that sounds quite unrelated to my question

Comment: My fault. I was extending kalm42's answer without proper understanding of the question. Sorry

Comment: no problem :) thanks still for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is organized on Next JS side the custom error page works only in production, As far as I understood it's done intentionally to show errors on d

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetaly this is how Next.js is designed. It's explicitly mentioned in their [documentation under the *Custom Error Page* section](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#more-advanced-error-page-customizing).

> `pages/_error.js` is only used in production. In development you’ll get an error with the call stack to know where the error originated from.

There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39198) about being able to render the `_error` page in development too.